# Time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity and non-random strings

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, kolmogorov-complexity

If $t$ is a time constructible function then we can define the **time-bounded Kolmogorov complexity** of a string $x$ as:

$C^t(x)$ = the size of the smallest program p that generates $x$ in $t(|x|)$ steps

We can also extend the **incompressibility** notion: a string $x$ is incompressible if $C^t(x) \ge |x|$ (otherwise $x$ is **compressible**).

Now we can define the function:

$f^t(n) = | \{ x \text{ : } |x|=n \text{ and } x \text{ is compressible with respect to } C^t \} |$

( $f^t(n)$ is the total number of compressible strings of length n ).

> What is the relation (if any) between $t$ and the rate of growth of $f$? Can we say something about it?

**EDIT:**
For example, can we choose $t$ to make $f$ grow polynomially? ... **NO**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that there is something that can be said generally, but off the cuff, the best I can see is that as $t$ increases, the number of compressible strings increases as well.

On the other hand, we certainly cannot pick a $t$ such that $f$ is polynomial.  Notice that if $t(|x|)<|x|$, then there isn't enough time to write anything.  On the other hand, strings of the form $yyz$ can be generated by programs of length $|y|+|z|<|x|$ and there are at least $2^{|x|/2}$ of those.  So by monotonicity, $f$ will always be at least this large.

Comment: thanks. I edited the question. Actually, to make $f$ grow polynomially we must change its definition to $f^t(n) = | \{ x : |x|\leq n \text{ and } C^t(x) \leq k \log{x} \} |$ and choose $t(x) = |x|^k$ (*P-printable*)